# Regex: Extract a part of a string eliminating specific patterns of it

Tags: python, regex, regex-negation

I have the following example of strings and I would like to only extract the middle part of it eliminating the patterns in front and at the back of each string:

Exp1: `Error: -This can be an example. (YT-0E8)`

Exp1: `Warning: -Warning can happen too (WP-003)`

Exp3: `Error: Error can happen this way as well. (PP-W28)`

I just want to get the following output:

Ans1: `-This can be an example.`

Ans2: `-Warning can happen too`

Ans3: `Error can happen this way as well.`

As you can see, I'm trying to eliminate the FIRST pattern in-front which can be either `Error:`  or `Warning:` , with a space right after the colon and the SECOND pattern which is the brackets with alphanumeric string and space in-front of it:  `(TT-T56)`

I've come up to this extent to match the front and back pattern, but can't find a way to complete them: `^(Warning: |Error: ).*\((\w+-\d+)\)$`

Any way to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a regex replacement approach here:

```py
inp = ["Error: -This can be an example. (YT-0E8)", "Warning: -Warning can happen too (WP-003)", "Error: Error can happen this way as well. (PP-W28)"]
output = [re.sub(r'^\w+:\s*|\s*\(.*?\)$', '', x) for x in inp]
print(output)
# ['-This can be an example.', '-Warning can happen too',
#  'Error can happen this way as well.']
```

This approach strips, alternatively, the leading label followed by colon or the trailing term in parentheses, leaving behind the content you want.

Comment: Thanks Tim! Great answer! But what if I wanted to extract the patterns to an array using the similar example?

`Error: -This can be an example. (YT-0E8)`

to

`["Error", "-This can be an example.", "YT-0E8"]`

You can see that the colon is removed from the first pattern match, and the brackets are removed in the second pattern match. Can you give me a suggestion on this?

Comment: Use, on each element: `re.findall(r'^(\w+):\s*(.*?)\s*\((.*?)\)', x)`